# Angular router error - Invalid configuration of route

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, redirect

Using angular 4, I am redirecting the route with an empty path to *navbar* component. So I have added `pathMatch: full` and I placed this entry at the top in routes array.

But I still get the following error:

> zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection:
>     **Invalid configuration of route ''**: Array cannot be specified ;
>     Zone: root ;
>     Task: Promise.then ;
>     Value: ZoneAwareError {
>     __zone_symbol__error: Error: Invalid configuration of route '': Array
>     cannot be specified
>     at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6405:43) [ => angular]

**route.component.ts**

```
import {Route} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from './navbar/navbar.component';
import {RegistrationComponent} from './registration/registration.component';

export const appRoutes:Route =[
  {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'navbar',
   pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
   path: 'home',
   component: NavbarComponent
  }, {
   path: 'navbar',
   component: NavbarComponent
  }, {
   path: 'registration',
   component: RegistrationComponent
  }
];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from './navbar/navbar.component';
import {RegistrationComponent} from './registration/registration.component';

import { appRoutes } from './app.route';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    RegistrationComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([appRoutes])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change

**From**

```
RouterModule.forRoot([appRoutes])
```

**To**

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
```

Comment: I forgot to declare appRoutes as an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
```

instead of

```
export const appRoutes:Route =[
```